# How does Hibernate get the AutoIncrement Value on Identity Insert

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am working on a high scale application of the order of 35000 Qps, using Hibernate and MySQL.

A large table has AutoIncrement Primary key, and generation defined is IDENTITY at Hibernate. Show Sql is true as well.

Whenever an Insert happens I see only one query being fired in DB, which is an

Insert statement.

Few Questions Follow:

1) I was wondering how does Hibernate get the AutoIncrement Value after insert?

2) If the answer is "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()", why does it not show up at VividCortex or in Show Sql Logs...?

3) How does  "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()" account for multiple autoincrements in different tables?

4) If MySql returns a value on Insert, why aren't the MySql clients built so that we can see what is being returned?

Thanks in Advance for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Practically, you can't do the same thing as the MySQL JDBC driver using another MySQL client. You'd have to write your own client that reads and writes the MySQL protocol.

The MySQL JDBC driver gets the last insert id by parsing packets of the MySQL protocol. The last insert id is returned in this protocol by a MySQL result set.

This is why `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` doesn't show up in query metrics. It's not calling that SQL statement, it's picking the integer out of the result set at the protocol level.

You asked how it's done internally. A relevant line of code is https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/8.0/src/main/protocol-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/protocol/a/result/OkPacket.java#L55

Basically, it parses an integer from a known position in a packet as it receives a result set.

I'm not going to go into any more detail about parsing the protocol. I don't have experience coding a MySQL protocol client, and it's not something I wish to do.

I think it would not be a good use of your time to implement your own MySQL client.

Answer (score 0):

1. It probably uses the [standard JDBC mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement-java.lang.String-int-) to get generated values.
2. It's not
3. You execute it imediately after inserting in one table, and you thus get the values that have been generated by that insert. But that's not what is being used, so it's irrelevant
4. Not sure what you mean by that: the MySQL JDBC driver allows doing that, using the standard JDBC API

Comment: 1)  "standard JDBC mechanism" How does it do it internally, I meant? How can I do the same thing from Mysql Client?

Comment: I have no idea of what you mean by "MySql Client". If you want to know how the MySQL JDBC driver does that internally, you'd have to read its source code.

Comment: By "MySql Client" I mean a place where user manually writes the queries , and on pressing Enter, the query goes to server to execute. What is special about the queries fired through Hibernate that it gets the AutoIncrement Value in return? When I execute a query manually I don't see any AutoIncrement getting returned.

Comment: You would execute a SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() in this client to know the last inserted ID. Unless that client allows displaying the generated IDs automatically.

Comment: So is my Application doing the same internally? i.e. execute SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()

Comment: I answered this question already. I doubt it. *It probably uses the standard JDBC mechanism to get generated values.*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202576/discussion-between-dipanshu-verma-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: No. I don't chat. And I'm in a train, making it hard.

Answer (score 0):

(Too long for a comment.)

- `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` uses the value already available in the connection.  (This may explain its absence from any log.)
- Each table has its own auto_inc value.
- (I don't know any details about Hibernate.)
- 35K qps is possible, but it won't be easy.
- Please give us more details on the queries -- SELECTs?  writes?  35K INSERTs?
- Are you batching the inserts in any way?  You *will need to do such*.
- What do you then use the auto_inc value in?
- Do you use BEGIN..COMMIT?  What value of autocommit?